# What is a record for a football player in converting consecutive penalties in official matches?

Tags: football, trivia, records

Various sources mentioned that [Mario Balotelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Balotelli) recently missed a penalty for the first time in his career (in a professional match).

For example [here](http://www.espn.co.uk/football/sport/story/240785.html):

> Balotelli has never failed to convert any of his previous 21 penalties in official matches but saw his remarkable run halted when Pepe Reina stooped low to save the Italian's effort to his right just after the hour mark.

And [another source](http://www.goal.com/en-gb/news/3276/serie-a/2013/09/22/4281759/balotelli-misses-first-penalty-of-his-career):

> The Italy striker has developed a reputation as a deadly penalty-taker and up until the miss against Napoli he had successfully converted all 26 of his spot-kicks for club and country.

- What is the largest number of consecutive penalties converted by a player in competitive matches?

Comment: Some statistics of remarkable penalty takers are mentioned in this question on Quora: [Who are some of the best penalty takers in the history of football?](http://www.quora.com/Football-soccer-2/Who-are-some-of-the-best-penalty-takers-in-the-history-of-football-and-has-a-record-to-prove-it)

Answer (score 9):

[Rickie Lambert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickie_Lambert) converted all of his 34 penalties for Southampton FC. (Although he missed some penalty kicks in some of his previous clubs. And after transfer from Southampton to Liverpool he did not convert his first penalty in a friendly against AC Milan.)

- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickie_Lambert#Penalty_record) which provides some further references. (Link to [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rickie_Lambert&oldid=683328080#Penalty_record).)
- [Masters from the penalty spot](http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=1913517.html); article on the UEFA website. (17 August 2013, [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=1913517.html))
- Daily Mail article [Right from the Le Tissier school! Lambert is Southampton's new penalty king as textbook spot-kick at West Brom preserves flawless record of 32 goals from 32](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2396552/Rickie-Lambert-preserves-perfect-penalty-record-Southampton-Premier-League-win-West-Bromwich.html) (19 August 2013, [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2396552/Rickie-Lambert-preserves-perfect-penalty-record-Southampton-Premier-League-win-West-Bromwich.html)
- Daily Mail article [Rickie Lambert's long-standing penalty scoring record comes to an end as Liverpool striker sees spot-kick saved in Milan friendly](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2714579/Rickie-Lamberts-long-standing-penalty-scoring-record-comes-end-Liverpool-striker-sees-spot-kick-saved-Milan-friendly.html) which includes list of his penalties. (3 August 2014, [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2714579/Rickie-Lamberts-long-standing-penalty-scoring-record-comes-end-Liverpool-striker-sees-spot-kick-saved-Milan-friendly.html))

Based on his [statistics on soccerway](http://int.soccerway.com/players/rickie-lambert/50849/), he scored penalty goals for Southampton in the following competitions:

- Premier League: 3 in [2012/13](http://int.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20122013/regular-season/), 3 in [2013/14](http://int.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20132014/regular-season/)
- Championship: 9 in [2011/12](http://int.soccerway.com/national/england/championship/2011-2012/regular-season/)
- League One: 8 in [2010/11](http://int.soccerway.com/national/england/league-one/2010-2011/regular-season/), 8 in [2009/10](http://int.soccerway.com/national/england/league-one/2009-2010/regular-season/)
- [2009-10 Football League Trophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009%E2%80%9310_Football_League_Trophy): in penalty shootout [against Torquay](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/8284894.stm), and in the final [against Carlisle United](http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2010/03/28/england/football-league-trophy/carlisle-united-fc/southampton-fc/912434/).

It is worth mentioning that only the last 6 penalties in this series were in Premier League, previously he played in lower competitions.

This only adds up to 33 penalties. I am not sure where the discrepancy from the sources saying that he scored 34 penalties comes from.

Comment: The statistics I've listed only add up to 31 penalties. I do not know where the difference between these numbers and the statistics from the sources I quoted come from.

Comment: Today he scored a penalty in the [match against Hull City](http://int.soccerway.com/matches/2013/11/09/england/premier-league/southampton-fc/hull-city-afc/1483563/). So if the number given by the sources were correct as of August 203, his series is now at 33.

Comment: I see that this information now appeared also in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickie_Lambert#Penalty_Record) about this player. Here is link to the [current revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rickie_Lambert&oldid=600943867#Penalty_Record); just in case the article changes in the future.

Comment: ...but, according to the other answers, this isn't the player with the most consecutive converted penalties.

Answer (score 7):

Peter Noble of Swindon Town.

Following taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Noble):

> Noble ended his career having scored every penalty he took. This
>   record of 28 consecutive penalties is widely believed to be a world
>   record. In 1985 a question about Noble's penalty kicks appeared in the
>   first edition of the popular board game 'Trivial Pursuit'.

Answer (score 5):

http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rune_%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m

Translated from the Swedish Wikipedia link:

About Rune Ångström:"

As a football player, he is renowned for the number of successful penalty kicks in a row: he made 57 successful consecutive penalties from 1949 to 1953 , and 53 consecutive pieces during the years 1942-1949

Answer (score 4):

Albanian [Ledio Pano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledio_Pano) has perfect record scoring over 50 penalties for various teams in Greece and Albania.

Sources:

- [Masters from the penalty spot](http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=1913517.html); article on the UEFA website
- [Which highest-capped player has the fewest caps? Plus: Perfect penalty takers](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2013/oct/02/highest-capped-player-the-knowledge), The Guardian

Answer (score 3):

[Matthew Le Tissier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Le_Tissier) was well known for his penalty taking ability. This isn't a definitive "he is the best", but his record of 47 out of 48 must be hard to beat!

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this. It was a honest attempt to answer the question and - as you can see from the timestamp - this answer appeared here before the information given in the other answers. (So it was, for some time, the best what we were able to find.)

Answer (score 3):

> **Gaizka Mendieta** was considered the ultimate penalty taker. There are
>   no records shown, even according to his own testimony, of him ever
>   missing a penalty during his professional career!

http://www.history-of-soccer.org/mendieta.html

> **Ivan Krstanović** (Croatia, 2000-present) The GNK Dinamo Zagreb forward
>   has by all accounts never missed a penalty in his career, assuring
>   UEFA.com that "it's at least 30 goals".
>
> **Hans-Joachim Abel** (Germany, 1972-84) ..., but Fortuna Düsseldorf, VfL
>   Bochum 1848 and FC Schalke 04 striker Abel is statistically the
>   Bundesliga's best, reportedly converting all 16 of his spot-kicks.
>
> **Ledio Pano** (Albania, 1986-2001) Midfielder Pano boasted a 100% record
>   in over 50 penalties in his career in Albania and Greece

http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=1913517.html

Answer (score 0):

Dave Juneman converted 42 consecutive penalties for Tooting and Mitcham United in the 1970s.

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE! Could you provide a source for this? If you could, this would be an excellent (if very obscure) answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Jonny Hubbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Hubbard) who played for [Glasgow Rangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rangers_F.C.) was another exceptionally good penalty taker. According to Wikipedia:

> Hubbard was nicknamed the "Penalty King" by Rangers fans, due to his exceptional record of 65 goals scored from 68 penalty kicks, 22 consecutively.

The reference given in Wikipedia article is: http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Football%3A+THE+PERFECT+PENALTY%3B+Model+yourself+on+van+Nistelrooy+says...-a0102522683

Comment: But how many did he make consecutively?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I [have edited](http://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/12143/revisions) the post and added information I found on Wikipedia.